# Solana/Phantom.app signMessage returns different signature if Auto-approve turned on

Tags: solana

Having problem verifying signMessage from solana in case when Auto-approve is turned on in Phantom.app.

Code is like this:

```
var message = "Sign in";
var encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
solana.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8").then(function(obj) {
    verified = nacl.sign.detached.verify(encodedMessage, obj.signature, obj.publicKey.toBytes());
...
```

Now this works perfectly fine if you connect with Phantom.app but as soon as you turn on Auto-approve in your Phantom.app it doesn't work anymore.

The signature is different if Auto-approve is on and if it's not on. Verification only works if Auto-approve is off.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on and how could this be overcome?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey P.I.Julius
I am also trying to handle log in with phantom wallet.
Could please kindly share your whole code?
So that I can refer to it.
Thanks!